# Docmd.Findrecord finds in textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using the docmd.Findrecord to find a record based on a value the user enter in a textbox. The problem is that Findrecord considers the textbox as a field and just keep finding the string in the field and not the records in the table I tricked the command by deleting the string in the textbox just before the search and replacing it back after the search.  How can I fix this without this extra trick ?  Here is the code I use:

```
Private Sub SearchRecord_Click()
Dim strwhat2find As String
If SearchTxt.Value = "" Then

Else
    strwhat2find = SearchTxt.Value
    SearchTxt.Value = ""
    DoCmd.FindRecord strwhat2find, acAnywhere, False, acSearchAll, True, acAll, True
    SearchTxt.Value = strwhat2find
End If
End Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: It depends what you want to accomplish. If you want to find a value in a table somewhere in the background I would recommend `DLookup()`. If you want to find it on your contineous form I would use a `recordset` and work with `.FindFirst`, `.FindNext`.

Comment: What I want to accomplish is to find and go to the record that contain whatever the user enter in the text box. In fact I want to duplicate the find record macro without having the find window opening.

Comment: Options are: 1) set form filter property; 2) RecordsetClone, FindFirst, and Bookmark to go to desired record without filtering.

Comment: I noticed something new now. When I search ( using find record or also FindNext) if the text I'm searching exist in two fields in the same record, the search get stuck in that same record. If the text exist in only one field, the search keeps going from one record to the other.